# django ForeignKey in for loop

Tags: django, for-loop, foreign-keys

i will like to show data in table from two models with ForeignKey:
i will use this models as example:

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['headline']
```

and now i will like to have dataTable showing all Reporters `last_name` , and latest Article `headline` related to each Reporter

this is my views.py

```
def reporters(request):
    reporters = Reporter.objects.all()
    total_reporters = Reporter.objects.count()
    context = dict(reporters=reporters, total_reporters=total_reporters)
    return render(request, 'reporters/reporters.html', context)
```

but this is only giving reporters name

```
{% for reporter in reporters %}

{{ reporter.last_name }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Perhaps this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770138/querying-foreignkey-nested-for-loop-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Reporter model write a method to get the latest Article:

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
    
    def get_latest_article(self):
        return self.article_set.latest('pub_date')
```

Now in your template you can write:

```
{% with latest_article=reporter.get_latest_article %}
    {{ latest_article.headline }}
    {{ latest_article.pub_date }}
{% endwith %}
```

**Note**: `latest` may raise a DoesNotExist exception if the reporter has no articles, you may need to use a try-except block to prevent any errors (return None in except block) and check in template if the value is not None.

Comment: Thank You , work perfectly.

`Note: latest may raise a DoesNotExist exception if the reporter has no articles, you may need to use a try-except block to prevent any errors (return None in except block) and check in template if the value is not None.`

No errors even if reporter don't have articles 

Thank you very much